# Rendered as PDF apply Lightning Design System

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning-design-system

I want to known suggestion about `lightning design system rendered as PDF`. I have a VF page that page `rendered as PDF` format. My page is also using `lightning design system`. but that designs are not rendered in `PDF` view. So any suggestion or Idea is most welcome. Here my code is

```
<apex:page renderAs="pdf" applyHtmlTag="false" sidebar="false" showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false">
    <html>
    <head>
        <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.SLDS, '/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system.min.css')}"/>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="slds">
        <div class="slds-grid slds-grid slds-wrap slds-grid--pull-padded" style="text-align: center;">

            <div class="slds-col--padded slds-size--1-of-1">
                BAR CODE HERE
            </div> 

            <div class="slds-col--padded slds-size--1-of-1">
                16JULCOM
            </div>

            <div class="slds-col--padded slds-size--1-of-1">
                00004
            </div>

            <div class="slds-col--padded slds-size--1-of-1"> 
                <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-grid--pull-padded">
                    <div class="slds-col--padded slds-size--1-of-3">Time Stamp 1</div>
                    <div class="slds-col--padded slds-size--1-of-3">Time Stamp 2</div>
                    <div class="slds-col--padded slds-size--1-of-3">Time Stamp 3</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Please share code else it will hard to assist with

Comment: I attached my code here @MohithShrivastava

Comment: Can you say ApplyHtMLtag=false and have html tag yourself written

Comment: Its does not work. I updated my code @MohithShrivastava

Comment: Everything should be under main div with class SLDS.I think you may need that

Comment: Also inspect to see if your browser shows any error that stylesheets did not load

Comment: No change. I need to suggestion. Is this possible or not. because rendered as pdf does not allowing Internal style class. only allowing Inline styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rendered as pdf does not allowing Internal and External style classes it only allowing Inline styles.

Answer (score 1):

LEX is not supported in RenderAs Pdf right now. See trailhead for lightning experience module.  [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/lex_dev_overview/units/lex_dev_overview_visualforce)

You have to remove it to render as PDF or you can use other JS libraries like Pdf.js

Answer (score 1):

You can not use SLDS when using **renderAs=PDF**. Not just that, but you also lose CSS properties like Grid and flex. However, if you want the Grid system in particular, then you can write custom CSS with **float** and **width** properties.

I have written in [detail the sample code](https://salesforceguides.com/index.php/2023/03/28/how-to-implement-grid-system-using-css-in-vf-page-with-renderas-pdf/) in my blog that uses the above properties and achieves a simple custom Grid system for PDFs in Visualforce page.

Answer (score -1):

Visualforce pdf supports internal and external css files. But the issue is SLDS css file is not supporting in Visualforce PDF for some reason.
The below URL works fine with internal CSS file(stored CSS file in Static resource)

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Creating_Professional_PDF_Documents_with_CSS_and_Visualforce