# Status of renderAs advanced_pdf

Tags: visualforce, pdf, renderas

I just wondering if this promising feature has been evolved or is evolving to GA

https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer17/release-notes/rn_vf_advanced_pdf.htm

Any info about current status or roadmap?

Comment: I'll ask around, but it seems that advanced_pdf is currently mapped to just pdf.

Comment: thanks sfdcfox, it would be too sad to see this pilot dying, because the need and power of a great pdf-generator is huge - at least among our clients

Answer (score 15):

As of Summer '18, this pilot program has been cancelled. The service didn't quite meet the scalability goals we needed. Safe harbor, we're working on a way to bring the program back and adapt it to support Lightning components as well.

Comment: Has this gone anywhere yet? I'm sure I'm not alone in really needing something other than the VFP based solutions which make us double our workload.

Comment: I'm also very interested in this feature as lack of advanced PDF rendering capabilities is really problematic