# How to generate PDF attachment of visualforce page with embeded lightning component?

Tags: lightning, aura, pdf, renderas

Is there any way to create PDF attachment for VF Page with Lightning Out component in it:

myContent.page:

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" controller="PageController" standardStylesheets="false" lightningStylesheets="true"
       sidebar="false">

<apex:includeLightning />

    <apex:form>

          Is main text

        <script>
            $Lightning.use("c:LightningApp", function() {
                $Lightning.createComponent("c:HeaderComponent",
                    "lightning",
                    function(cmp) {
                        // do some stuff
                    });
            });
       </script>
  </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

HeaderComponent.cmp:

```
<aura:component description="HeaderComponent">
   <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />

     <div aura:id="main" id="mainDiv">

          <p> Is Embedded Text </p>

    </div>
</aura:component>
```

Apex:

```
Attachment pdfattachment = new Attachment();

pdfattachment.Name = system.now() + '.pdf'; //put your attachment name
PageReference pdfPage = new PageReference( '/apex/myContent');

pdfattachment.Body = pdfPage.getContentAsPDF();
pdfattachment.ContentType = 'application/pdf';
pdfattachment.parentId = 'XXXXXX000AM5QL'; //(Put your Parent Object ID here)

insert pdfattachment;
```

When I open VF page with embedded component" -  I can see both "Is main text" and "Is Embedded Text"
But when I open created attachment - only "Is main text" is populated. Is there any way how we can store the content from VF Page and its embedded component as PDF in the system?

Comment: renderAsPDF does not run JS on visualforce, so it is not possible so far

Comment: @kurunve. I am trying to use pdfPage.getContentAsPDF(), not "renderAsPDF"

Comment: It uses same engine behind -- server-side renderer for renderAsPDF and getContentAsPDF

Comment: @kurunve any workaround?

Comment: @ValentinePotapov There is no workaround. You cannot load a component in a PDF because components require JavaScript, which is not supported in a PDF. This is one of the main reasons you'd want to use plain Visualforce instead of a component.

Comment: @sfdcfox Example: we can assign component content from vf page to apex controller variable. After that we can use the same controller on vf page with RenderAsPDF. Exactly as here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/224609/render-as-pdf-in-table-format-in-lightning-component.

Comment: @sfdcfox. But what I am thinking - can we do the same but for creating an attachment in the backend (not opening the page)?

Comment: @ValentinePotapov Again, that question shows that we can't render components as PDF.