# Advanced PDF status update?

Tags: visualforce, pdf, release-notes

I'm interested in rendering Visualforce as `advanced_pdf`, but I can't find any new details since it went [Pilot in Summer'17](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer17/release-notes/rn_vf_advanced_pdf.htm).

Are there any updates?

Comment: As of now we don't have any update on this. 
 https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/215619/status-of-renderas-advanced-pdf