# renderAS = "advanced_pdf" with API Version 46.0 not rendering PDF with SDLS framework

Tags: visualforce, pdf, renderas

**Why is the renderAS = "advanced_pdf" not working ?**
         Trying to apply SDLS to existing classic visualforce page. 
 This page is renderedAs a 'PDF'. If I add renderAS = "advanced_pdf"  the page 
 looks exactly like the old classic page, if i remove the renderAS tag, it displays with the lightning look.

```
<apex:page controller="ControllerNew" renderAs="advanced_pdf" language="{!language}" applyBodyTag="false" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false">

    <div class="slds"> 
        <body>
         .......
    </div>

</apex>
```

[image: naved_Pd]

Answer (score 4):

Advanced PDF is - as far as I'm aware - not yet GA and still in Pilot.

Source: https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer17/release-notes/rn_vf_advanced_pdf.htm

There have been no official updates since then and it seems that this feature has been canceled altogether. In that case, we just have to wait until they come up with something better.

Source: [Status of renderAs advanced_pdf](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/215619/status-of-renderas-advanced-pdf/260332#260332)

You can still try and ask Salesforce to enable that feature for you but I doubt they will or even can do it. But it may be worth a try.

Comment: I was under the impression that the advanced PDF pilot has been completely retired.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Is there a workaround to render a VFP as PDF  that has the SDLS styling. ?

Comment: The only way to render PDF with any styling, that I found, was to literally use the style attribute on the various elements - CSS was not applied when I tried this sort of thing.